# DHTMLX Scheduler: Add event to section

Tags: javascript, scheduler, dhtmlx

I have this scheduler with sections.
https://snag.gy/r96y1c.jpg

I am using a custom popup to add events to this section and my current config when i click add on the popup is this:

```
scheduler.addEvent({
    start_date: newDate,
    end_date:   newEndDate,
    text: "Booking",
    sections: { unit: MessageRoom }
});
```

where MessageRoom is the number of the section.

I even change the config to have room option too but the event always add to the first section.

What I am doing wrong?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a value for a property that is mapped to units view section ('section_id', or another property depending on your config). If you do so, event will be created in the specified section.

```
scheduler.addEvent({
    start_date: new Date(2017,5,30,3),
    end_date:   new Date(2017,5,30,8),
    text: "Booking",
    section_id: 3
});
```

[Snippet how it works](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/snippet/a0634319)